# Jetpack Compose - Show a shadow at top of the Bottom Sheet with

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to show a shadow at the top of the Jetpack Compose bottom sheet(like in the attached picture). I tried to use ModalBottomSheetLayout and BottomDrawer composables' elevation values. The elevation seems like adding the shadow at the bottom of the sheet. How could I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Modifier.shadow(elevation = X.dp)? X would most likely have to be a larger than usual number to be visible at the top.

Comment: This just adds a shadow to the screen. It looks like a border has been applied to a screen. This is not the desirable effect.